# How to make an overflowing GridView.count adaptive without resorting to hard code?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

As a beginner, I faced the problem of the adaptability of my code. I have overflowed GridView, as I understand it in the daysBuilder() method.[This is my crowded GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEtPq.jpg)
I don't want to hardcode (with the help of fitting via childAspectRatio) and make it adaptive for all devices, please tell me how it can be done. [This is what it should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kevIo.jpg)

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:calendar/themes/colors.dart';
import 'package:calendar/themes/project_icons_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const CalendarApp());
}

class CalendarApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const CalendarApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const Text(
              '2023',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: ProjectColors.white,
                fontSize: 17,
                fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    log('Day Calendar');
                  },
                  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                  icon: const Icon(ProjectIcons.calandar_day),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    log('Week Calendar');
                  },
                  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                  icon: const Icon(ProjectIcons.calandar_week),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    log('Month Calendar');
                  },
                  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                  icon: const Icon(ProjectIcons.calandar_month),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    log('Year Calendar');
                  },
                  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                  icon: const Icon(ProjectIcons.calandar_year),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: ProjectColors.dark,
        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      backgroundColor: ProjectColors.dark,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          mainAxisSpacing: 8,
          crossAxisSpacing: 8,
          childAspectRatio: 0.7,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: Calendar(year: 2023).yearBuilder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Calendar {
  int year;

  Calendar({required this.year});

  static const Map<int, String> monthInYear = {
    1: 'January',
    2: 'February',
    3: 'March',
    4: 'April',
    5: 'May',
    6: 'June',
    7: 'July',
    8: 'August',
    9: 'September',
    10: 'October',
    11: 'November',
    12: 'December',
  };

  List<Widget> yearBuilder() {
    final List<Widget> months = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < monthInYear.length + 1; i++) {
      months.add(monthBuilder(i));
    }
    return months;
  }

  Widget monthBuilder(int month) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        log('Tap: ${monthInYear[month]}');
      },
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, bottom: 8),
            child: Text(
              '${monthInYear[month]}',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: ProjectColors.white,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 125,
            child: GridView.count(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              crossAxisCount: 7,
              mainAxisSpacing: 8,
              children: daysBuilder(year, month),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> daysBuilder(int year, int month) {
    final List<Widget> numsList = [];
    int daysInMonth = DateTime(year, month + 1, 0).day;
    for (var i = 1; i < daysInMonth + 1; i++) {
      numsList.add(
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              '$i',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: ProjectColors.white,
                fontSize: 12,
                fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const Icon(
              Icons.pentagon,
              size: 4,
              color: ProjectColors.secondaryBlue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return numsList;
  }
}
```

GridView does not obey the height of the sizedbox and the childAspectRatio method does not suit me either

Answer (score 0):

You can either use wrap instead of GridView.count in monthsBuilder function.
Code:

```
Widget monthBuilder(int month) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        log('Tap: ${monthInYear[month]}');
      },
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, bottom: 8, top: 10),
            child: Text(
              '${monthInYear[month]}',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 125,
            child: Wrap(

              spacing: 5,
              runSpacing: 5,
              children: daysBuilder(year, month),
            ),

            // GridView.count(
            //   physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            //   crossAxisCount: 7,
            //   mainAxisSpacing: 8,
            //   children: daysBuilder(year, month),
            // ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Or, you can use a flexible widget with a fitted box on text on daysBuilder function.

Code:

```
List<Widget> daysBuilder(int year, int month) {
    final List<Widget> numsList = [];
    int daysInMonth = DateTime(year, month + 1, 0).day;
    for (var i = 1; i < daysInMonth + 1; i++) {
      numsList.add(
        Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 4,
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Text(
                  '$i',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.pentagon,
                size: 4,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return numsList;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, wrapped the Icon() in Expanded().

```
  List<Widget> daysBuilder(int year, int month) {
    final List<Widget> numsList = [];
    int daysInMonth = DateTime(year, month + 1, 0).day;
    for (var i = 1; i < daysInMonth + 1; i++) {
      numsList.add(
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              '$i',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: ProjectColors.white,
                fontSize: 12,
                fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const Expanded(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.pentagon,
                size: 4,
                color: ProjectColors.secondaryBlue,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return numsList;
  }
}
```